# Why doesn't email containing 'sandbox.paypal.com' get to a gmail recipient?

Tags: php, security, email, html-email, paypal-sandbox

I've come across something really weird. If I try to send and email containing the string "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/" using PHP's mail function, it NEVER gets send, and **this is happening on all all webhosts I've tried it and on my testing vm (regardless of sending method: msmtp and gmail smth on my vm, sendmail or postfix mta on the servers...) and regardless of the context around this string, headers (plain text mail, html mail) recipient(s), senders**.

Is this some kind of security measure implemented globally or what? And btw, the string "https://www.paypal.com/" doesn't cause the behavior.

Note: there is no error and the `mail(...)` function returns `true`, it's simply that the email never gets to the destination.

---

Update: it seems a gmail specific problem, I tried sending to non-gmail hosted accounts and it works fine. on gmail accounts, *some* of the test email arrive but with something like a 30min delay! (maybe gmail spam filter block some of the mails)

Comment: Could you post some code?

Comment: I am sure it is not globally implemented. Have you tried sending through different servers ? It could be your mail provider specifically blocking it.

Comment: What happens if you do https://www.subdomain.example.com or sandbox.example.com?

Comment: the code can be as simple as `mail('your@email.com', 'test', 'something https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/')`. the string is "paypal.sandbox.com" - using just the word "sandbox" doesn;t trigger the effect. misspelling "paypal" cancels the effect. now I'm testing on a vidahost shared hosting account, a client's server and my vm that uses msmtp and smtp.gmail.com

Comment: @tim.baker nothing, the problem is just for "paypal.sandbox.com"!

Comment: You're probably just annoying some paranoid spam or phishing filter. I presume you tried different [recipient] email providers?

Comment: @Boann yeah, I guess it's gmail's spam filter! but there is a problem: it doesn't just mark it as spam! it either (a) makes it just disappear (like 90% of the time) or (b) makes it show up in spam with something like a 30min delay since it was actually sent, and chooses between (a) and (b) randomly

Comment: yes, definately spamfilters involved

Comment: @cIph3r shouldn't a spam filter just mark it as spam, not "make it disappear" or "randomly delay it?

Comment: @NeuronQ

No. Most ISPs or MailSPs filter spam on different levels, 
some are marked only, others were immediately deleted.

there are also lerning-algorithms involved, making the behaviour differ

Comment: @cIph3r nice to know. what amazes me is that regular "paypal.com" links work, just the darned "sandbox.paypal.com" that can't even be used for nothing else than testing got labeled as "fishy"...